# Oracle 12c executing Stored procedure gives empty result

Tags: java, oracle

I am trying to execute the stored procedure using the java code. I am using Ojdbc 7, Jdk 1.8.

I have two databases with the same data but different versions. One with Oracle 10g and another with Oracle 12c

Plsql executes successfully and I see the fetched data in both Oracle 10g, Oracle 12c.

My Java code works fine with Oracle 10g version. But in Oracle 12c version I get the empty result.

```
declare
 OFFERLIST_ID_TY OFFERLIST_ID_TYPES;
 OFFERLIST_ID_T OFFERLIST_ID_TYPE;
 OFFERS_INFO_TY OFFERS_INFO_TYPE;

begin

OFFERLIST_ID_T:=OFFERLIST_ID_TYPE('1234','MM');
OFFERLIST_ID_TY:=OFFERLIST_ID_TYPES(OFFERLIST_ID_T);


OFFERS(OFFERLIST_ID_TY,OFFERS_INFO_TY);

FOR i IN OFFERS_INFO_TY.FIRST..OFFERS_INFO_TY.LAST  LOOP
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name: '|| OFFERS_INFO_TY(i).SERVICE_NAME);
    END LOOP;

    END;
```

Java class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        Connection connection  = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@db:1521:sid", "user",
                "pwd");
        ArrayList<Struct> OFFERListIdType = new ArrayList<Struct>();
        OFFERListIdType.add(
                ((OracleConnection) connection).createStruct("OFFERLIST_ID_TYPE", new String[] { "1234", "MM" }));

        Array array_of_records = ((OracleConnection) connection).createARRAY("OFFERLIST_ID_TYPES",
                OFFERListIdType.toArray(new Struct[] {}));

        CallableStatement stmt = connection
                .prepareCall("{ call OFFERS(?,?) }");

        stmt.setArray(1, array_of_records);
        stmt.registerOutParameter(2, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.ARRAY, "OFFERS_INFO_TYPE");

        stmt.execute();

        System.out.println("Executed");
        Object[] data = (Object[]) ((Array) stmt.getObject(2)).getArray();
        System.out.println("Size:" + data.length);

        stmt.close();
        connection.close();

    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
}
```

The ouput
**`System.out.println("Size:" + data.length);`**

Gives empty but the same procedure gives data in the DB with the same data in oracle 10g.

Can somebody help?

This is a development database. There are many schemas for developers which  share a common code base.

Comment: I assume the data in your 12c instance is committed - you haven't just inserted it in the client/session you're testing the call with, but not committed to make it visible from the Java session?

Comment: @AlexPoole. Thank you for help. Could please elaborate bit. How can I set oracle 12c to be visible to Java session

Comment: Have you just inserted the data you're expecting to see? If so, have you issued a `commit`?

Comment: @AlexPoole. I have inserted the data. But cannot see. There is no commit issued. I have also not issued commit in oracle 10g

Comment: Is this a development database?

Comment: @APC. Yes it is

Comment: Follow up question: do you have lots of different schemas for developers which share a common code base (tables, types, etc)?

Comment: @APC. Yes there are many schemass that share common code base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "there are many schemass that share common code base"

It's possible you are running into Bug 21068213, or a variant of it. There seems to be some problems in 12cR1, such that objects in one schema are confused with identical objects in another schema. Maybe it's a leak in the multi-tenancy code.

Anyway, there is a patch for this bug. So it's worth contacting Oracle Support (assuming you have a contract) to see whether this bug is what is causing your problem. Certainly get your DBAs involved.

Comment: Thank you. Could you help me if there is reference to this bug and patch fix.

Comment: I have provided the Bug Number. You should be able to find it through the MyOracleSupport portal.